# How can I send a request with Axios to a URL with a query string?

Tags: javascript, url, axios, query-string

I am trying to upgrade a working piece of code from Axios 0.27.2 to 1.0.0 and the way a URL with a query string is handled seems to break. That is, I get a 404 response and the actual URL used looks different than before in that the question mark is missing.

The URL looks like this: https://my.server.com/some/path?foo=bar&baz=abc
Previous axios used that. In the 1.0.0 version the actual URL sent, as reported in the error, is: https://my.server.com/some/pathfoo=bar&baz=abc

Similar questions all revolve around how to build a query string and the fact that axios accepts a params object for that. In my case, I am getting a URL from elsewhere that contains / may contain a query string already. How can I convince Axios to use this URL without changing it in some way?

Comment: Can you share the before and after code using Axios to provide additional context?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Axios and is under review. Looks like your link is the thread to follow for an outcome of a breaking change

Comment: Yep, looks like it. Alas I found that ticket a few minutes *after* asking on SO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4999

This is a bug in Axios 1.0.0, fixed in 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get('my-url', {
  params: {
    foo: "baz",
    baz: "abc",
  }
}).then(...)
```

Is need to specify if is CORS REQUEST (Set axios options, before request)

Comment: As explained, the querystring is already part of the URL. I want to avoid parsing the querystring just to have Axios re-generate it from the parsed data.

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this by building a function to split the received url into objects containing a base url and params before passing to axios.

```js
function getUrlParams (url) {
const fullUrl = url;

const splitUrl = fullUrl.split("?");

const newUrl = splitUrl[0];

const paramsArray = splitUrl[1].split("&");

let paramsObj = {};

for(let i = 0; i < paramsArray.length; i++)
{
 const arr = paramsArray[i].split("=");
 const keyName = arr[0];
 const value = arr[1];
  paramsObj = {...paramsObj, [keyName]: value};
}
const data = {
base: newUrl,
params: paramsObj
}
return data;
}


const url = getUrlParams("https://my.server.com/some/path?foo=bar&baz=abc");

console.log(url)
```

Then for axios call you can do

```
axios.post(url.base, null, { params: url.params})
```